# Spline smoothening using statsmodel within Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, smoothing

I need to do group by smoothening of sales percentage values which could be erratic due to out of stock situations. I have my data in a Pandas dataframe. Here is the code I am trying:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
s = base_data1.groupby(['MDSE_ITEM_I','CO_LOC_I'])\
.transform(lambda x: UnivariateSpline(np.arange(x.count()), x['PCT_TILL_DATE'].value, s=x.count()))
```

Here I am passing `np.arange(x.count())` as `x` monotonically increasing array and passing values of Pandas series `x['PCT_TILL_DATE'].value` as `y` with good enough smoothing factor `s` as `x.count()`. However I am getting error:

> KeyError: ('PCT_TILL_DATE', u'occurred at index GREG_D')

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to select the column you want, because `transform()` already turns it into a Series, which you cant index like that.

Also, `UnitvariateSpline` returns a 'fitted' object which you need to call again with your desired x-output to get some actual values.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

n = 16
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1': np.cos(np.linspace(0,np.pi*4, n)),
                   'data2': np.random.randn(n),
                   'class_a': np.array([0]*(n//2)+[1]*(n//2)),
                   'class_b': np.array([1]*n)})

def grpfunc(grp):

    n = len(grp)
    x = np.arange(n)

    spl = UnivariateSpline(x, grp.values, s=n)

    return spl(x)

df.groupby(['class_a', 'class_b']).transform(grpfunc)
```

[image]